# ESP 32 unable to connect to https website and return the data using GET

Tags: esp32

I have created a ThingHTTP below:

```
https://api.thingspeak.com/apps/thinghttp/send_request?api_key=BVLJ7A6KNK9VVAYK
```

In my browser I could see the reply. But I am unable to make this work in my ESP32. I understand that this is a https so I would have to declare the root cert details. I have tried to modify based on this tutorial:

```
https://github.com/witnessmenow/arduino-sample-api-request/blob/master/ESP8266/HTTP_GET/HTTP_GET.ino
```

My code as follows:

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>

//------- Replace the following! ------
char ssid[] = "SSID";       // your network SSID (name)
char password[] = "pass";  // your network key

// For Non-HTTPS requests
// WiFiClient client;

// For HTTPS requests
WiFiClientSecure client;


// Just the base of the URL you want to connect to
#define TEST_HOST "https://api.thingspeak.com/apps/thinghttp/send_request?api_key=BVLJ7A6KNK9VVAYK"


const char *server_cert = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"
                                  "MIIDdzCCAl+gAwIBAgIEAgAAuTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBaMQswCQYDVQQGEwJJ\n"
                                  "RTESMBAGA1UEChMJQmFsdGltb3JlMRMwEQYDVQQLEwpDeWJlclRydXN0MSIwIAYD\n"
                                  "VQQDExlCYWx0aW1vcmUgQ3liZXJUcnVzdCBSb290MB4XDTAwMDUxMjE4NDYwMFoX\n"
                                  "DTI1MDUxMjIzNTkwMFowWjELMAkGA1UEBhMCSUUxEjAQBgNVBAoTCUJhbHRpbW9y\n"
                                  "ZTETMBEGA1UECxMKQ3liZXJUcnVzdDEiMCAGA1UEAxMZQmFsdGltb3JlIEN5YmVy\n"
                                  "VHJ1c3QgUm9vdDCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAKMEuyKr\n"
                                  "mD1X6CZymrV51Cni4eiVgLGw41uOKymaZN+hXe2wCQVt2yguzmKiYv60iNoS6zjr\n"
                                  "IZ3AQSsBUnuId9Mcj8e6uYi1agnnc+gRQKfRzMpijS3ljwumUNKoUMMo6vWrJYeK\n"
                                  "mpYcqWe4PwzV9/lSEy/CG9VwcPCPwBLKBsua4dnKM3p31vjsufFoREJIE9LAwqSu\n"
                                  "XmD+tqYF/LTdB1kC1FkYmGP1pWPgkAx9XbIGevOF6uvUA65ehD5f/xXtabz5OTZy\n"
                                  "dc93Uk3zyZAsuT3lySNTPx8kmCFcB5kpvcY67Oduhjprl3RjM71oGDHweI12v/ye\n"
                                  "jl0qhqdNkNwnGjkCAwEAAaNFMEMwHQYDVR0OBBYEFOWdWTCCR1jMrPoIVDaGezq1\n"
                                  "BE3wMBIGA1UdEwEB/wQIMAYBAf8CAQMwDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgEGMA0GCSqGSIb3\n"
                                  "DQEBBQUAA4IBAQCFDF2O5G9RaEIFoN27TyclhAO992T9Ldcw46QQF+vaKSm2eT92\n"
                                  "9hkTI7gQCvlYpNRhcL0EYWoSihfVCr3FvDB81ukMJY2GQE/szKN+OMY3EU/t3Wgx\n"
                                  "jkzSswF07r51XgdIGn9w/xZchMB5hbgF/X++ZRGjD8ACtPhSNzkE1akxehi/oCr0\n"
                                  "Epn3o0WC4zxe9Z2etciefC7IpJ5OCBRLbf1wbWsaY71k5h+3zvDyny67G7fyUIhz\n"
                                  "ksLi4xaNmjICq44Y3ekQEe5+NauQrz4wlHrQMz2nZQ/1/I6eYs9HRCwBXbsdtTLS\n"
                                  "R9I4LtD+gdwyah617jzV/OeBHRnDJELqYzmp\n"
                                  "-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";


void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);

  // Connect to the WiFI
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.println("");

  // Wait for connection
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connected to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  //--------

  // Checking the cert is the best way on an ESP32
  // This will verify the server is trusted.
  client.setCACert(server_cert);

  // If you don't want to verify the server
  // Unlike the fingerprint method of the ESP8266 which expires frequently
  // the cert lasts years, so I don't see much reason to ever
  // use this on the ESP32
  // client.setInsecure();

  makeHTTPRequest();
}

void makeHTTPRequest() {
  delay(5000);
  // Opening connection to server (Use 80 as port if HTTP)
  if (!client.connect(TEST_HOST, 443))
  {
    Serial.println(F("Connection failed"));
    return;
  }

  // give the esp a breather
  yield();
  client.connect(TEST_HOST, 443);
  // Send HTTP request
  client.print(F("GET "));
  // This is the second half of a request (everything that comes after the base URL)
  client.print(""); // %2C == ,
  client.println(F(" HTTP/1.1"));

  //Headers
  client.print(F("Host: "));
  client.println(TEST_HOST);

  client.println(F("Cache-Control: no-cache"));

  if (client.println() == 0)
  {
    Serial.println(F("Failed to send request"));
    return;
  }
  //delay(100);
  // Check HTTP status
  char status[32] = {0};
  client.readBytesUntil('\r', status, sizeof(status));
  if (strcmp(status, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK") != 0)
  {
    Serial.print(F("Unexpected response: "));
    Serial.println(status);
    return;
  }

  // Skip HTTP headers
  char endOfHeaders[] = "\r\n\r\n";
  if (!client.find(endOfHeaders))
  {
    Serial.println(F("Invalid response"));
    return;
  }

  // This is probably not needed for most, but I had issues
  // with the Tindie api where sometimes there were random
  // characters coming back before the body of the response.
  // This will cause no hard to leave it in
  // peek() will look at the character, but not take it off the queue
  while (client.available() && client.peek() != '{')
  {
    char c = 0;
    client.readBytes(&c, 1);
    Serial.print(c);
    Serial.println("BAD");
  }

  // While the client is still availble read each
  // byte and print to the serial monitor
  while (client.available()) {
    char c = 0;
    client.readBytes(&c, 1);
    Serial.print(c);
  }
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

the program was able to compile, and was able to run until it shows it connect to the network. But then it returned "Connection failed!" I believe it stuck at this line :

```
if (!client.connect(TEST_HOST, 443))
```

I am not sure what is the problem here. Comments appreciated.

Comment: Try creating a properly formatted HTTP request. Try also connecting to a server not a web page. There are so many things wrong with your GET request I don't know where to start...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things wrong with your GET request (which are nothing to do with Arduino - just learn the basics of the protocol you are trying to use *before* you use it):

- You are trying to open a socket to a URL not to a server. That can never work. Connect to the server instead (hint: the server, or "FQDN", is the bit between the `https://` and the next `/`).
- You aren't providing any path in your `GET` request, only a comment that says what you should provide.  Hint: the path is everything that comes after (and including) the `/` following the FQDN.
- Your `Host:` header should contain just the FQDN, not the whole URL. By now you should know what the FQDN is.
- You should also include `Connection: close` in your headers to inform the server you won't be keeping the socket open.

Correct those problems and you might begin to see something useful happening.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Been new to this. Guess I have started at the wrong place. Anyhow after implementing what you have said, and other minor mistakes, it seems to be working. I found out that I have to change the certificates for the website, there are a few types. Anyway thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

The piece of code below is from a firmware code I've been programming lately to use on Tensilica's Xtensa LX6/7 compatible MCUs (ESP32). The code below makes an HTTPS request using WIFIClientsecure library.

```
String GetInfoFromDataverse(String url) {
  //Check WiFi connection status
    
  if(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
    mserial.printStrln("WiFi Disconnected");
    if (connect2WIFInetowrk()){
      GetInfoFromDataverse(url);
    }
  }
            
  int str_len = SERVER_URL.length() + 1; // Length (with one extra character for the null terminator)
  char SERVER_URL_char [str_len];    // Prepare the character array (the buffer) 
  SERVER_URL.toCharArray(SERVER_URL_char, str_len);    // Copy it over 
    
  client.stop();
  client.setCACert(HARVARD_ROOT_CA_RSA_SHA1);
    
  if (!client.connect(SERVER_URL_char, SERVER_PORT)) {
      mserial.printStrln("Cloud server URL connection FAILED!");
      mserial.printStrln(SERVER_URL_char);
      int server_status = client.connected();
      mserial.printStrln("Server status code: " + String(server_status));
      return "";
  }
  
  mserial.printStrln("Connected to the dataverse of Harvard University"); 
  mserial.printStrln("");
  
  // We now create a URI for the request
  mserial.printStr("Requesting URL: ");
  mserial.printStrln(url);

  // Make a HTTP request and add HTTP headers    
  // post header
  String postHeader = "GET https://" + SERVER_URL + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n";
  postHeader += "Host: " + SERVER_URL + ":" + String(SERVER_PORT) + "\r\n";
  //postHeader += "X-Dataverse-key: " + API_TOKEN + "\r\n";
  postHeader += "Content-Type: text/json\r\n";
  postHeader += "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml,application/json,text/json;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n";
  postHeader += "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate\r\n";
  postHeader += "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7\r\n";
  postHeader += "User-Agent: AeonLabs LDAD Smart DAQ device\r\n";
  postHeader += "Keep-Alive: 300\r\n";
  postHeader += "Connection: keep-alive\r\n";
  postHeader += "Accept-Language: en-us\r\n";

  // request tail
  String tail = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n\r\n";

  // content length
  int contentLength = tail.length();
  postHeader += "Content-Length: " + String(contentLength, DEC) + "\n\n";
  
  // send post header
  int postHeader_len=postHeader.length() + 1; 
  char charBuf0[postHeader_len];
  postHeader.toCharArray(charBuf0, postHeader_len);
  client.print(charBuf0);
  
  mserial.printStrln("======= Headers =======");
  mserial.printStrln(charBuf0);
  mserial.printStrln("======= End of Headers =======");
  
  // Read all the lines of the reply from server and print them to mserial
  String responseHeaders = "";

  mserial.printStr("Waiting for server response...");
  long timeout= millis();
  long ttl=millis()-timeout;
  while (client.connected() && abs(ttl) < 30000) { // 30 sec.
    ttl=millis()-timeout;      
    responseHeaders = client.readStringUntil('\n');
    if (responseHeaders == "\r") {
      break;
    }
  }
  if (abs(ttl) < 30000){
    mserial.printStrln("OK");
  }else{
    mserial.printStrln("timed out.");  
  }
  
  String responseContent = client.readStringUntil('\n');
  client.stop();

  return responseContent;
  }
```